# SimplexmlElement - xpath using programmatically registered namespaces

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I am trying to parse some XML with Xpath. The functionality I am looking for is programmatically registering a namespace with a specific prefix if no existing prefix is found.

When I use the prefix in my Xpath query I am getting an empty array back, which indicates to me the Xpath is valid it is just not returning any results.

Here is a sample of the XML I am working with. Please note this is a simplified version of my actual code, it is done to illustrate my problem.

```
$xml =  <<<EOD
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
    <title> somdomain - RSS Video Feed</title>
    <link>http://www.somdomain.com/</link>
    <description>Latest Videos Released on somdomain</description>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <pubDate>Thu, 19 Sep 2013 16:53:29 GMT</pubDate>
    <lastBuildDate>Thu, 19 Sep 2013 16:53:29 GMT</lastBuildDate>
    <image>
    <title>RSS Video Feed</title>
    <url>
    http://somdomain/cb/white.png
    </url>
    <link>http://www.somdomain.com/</link>
    </image>
    <link xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" href="http://www.somdomain.com/rss/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
        <item>
            <title>The title </title>
            <link>
            http://www.somdomain.com/watch/8487128/
            </link>
            <description>
             <IMG border="1" src="http://cdn1.image.somdomain.php/8.jpg" />  <BR/> Length: 07:08 <BR/> Keywords:
            </description>
            <pubDate>Thu, 19 Sep 2013 16:00:11 GMT</pubDate>
            <guid>
            http://www.somdomain.com/watch/
            </guid>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
EOD;
//default namespace
$d = "x";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
//there will only be one element here, $prefix is an empty string and 
// $url is http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
foreach($ns as $prefix=>$url)
{
     //no prefix so use $d
    if($prefix=="")
    {
        $prefix = $d;
    }
    //register the namespace
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace($prefix, $url);
}


$result = $xml->xpath('/x:rss/x:channel/x:item');
//nothing
print_r($result);
```

I'm not sure why this is not working. I'm thinking registering the namespace should essentially alias the existing namespace thus "x:rss/x:channel/x:item" should be a valid query. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, you *might* want to edit the `//title` element since you already removed all that URLs. ;)

Comment: @JensErat Took me a while to spot what you meant! ROFL!

Comment: @JensErat - thanks for the heads up, looks like I missed a spot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, registering namespaces for your XPath based on how they are aliased in the document is generally a bad idea anyway: it may seem easier, but the prefixes could change without notice, whereas the actual namespace names (URIs) would stay the same. (e.g. generated code might simply use prefixes like `ns1:`, `ns2:`, etc; these could easily get swapped around later).

Instead, you should look at the actual namespaces you care about, and choose your own prefixes for them. In this case, your comment already points out that the only namespace involved is `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`. If any are added later, you won't have any code using them, so registering prefixes for them won't do you any good anyway.

So replace your entire loop with this one line:

```
 $xml->registerXPathNamespace('x', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
```

Secondly, you have to think about which elements are actually in that namespace. Although it has no prefix, it is declared inside the `link` element, so it applies as the default namespace only for that part of the document. Outside of that "scope", there is no `xmlns` attribute to declare a default namespace, so other elements are in *the namespace which has no name*.

As [Jens Erat points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18904296/157957), to reference those elements in XPath, you just don't use a namespace prefix at all:

```
$result = $xml->xpath('/rss/channel/item');
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<rss/>` element has no namespace defined, only the `<link href="http://www.somdomain.com/rss/" />` element (and all descendants) have this.

Use the query

```
/rss/channel/item
```

instead. You will need the namespace if you start selecting this `<link/>` element (or below that):

```
/rss/channel/x:link/@href
```